# Nuxt Auth Module For Login not working while data successfully returning from backend

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

I have laravel passport based API where I am requesting from my `nuxt` app with login data  and data responding in the below format

```
{
"status": "success",
"token": "MySecret-Token",
"user": {
    "id": 1002,
    "name": "Shakhwat hossain",
    "avatar": "https:someimageapi.com/avatar.jpg",
    "mobile_no": "01834394****",
    "email": "shakhawat@limmexbd.com",
    "area_id": 1,
    "sub_area_id": 0,
}
```

but login not working in `nuxt` application using `nuxt-auth` module version 5.0.0-1608140074.47635f0

here is my login method

```
async login() {
  try {
    let response = await this.$auth.loginWith("local", { data: this.form });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data.message);
  }
},

**and here is my nuxt auth setting in nuxt.config.js**


  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'token',
          required: false,
          type: 'Bearer',
          // maxAge: 31536000,
        },
        user: {
          property: 'user',
          autoFetch: false,
          propertyName: false
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/login', method: 'post' },
          logout: { url: '/logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/user', method: 'get' }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by set  required = true to token

```
auth: {
cookie: { options: { secure: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' } },
redirect: {
  login: '/login',
  logout: '/',
  callback: '/login',
  home: '/dashboard'
},
strategies: {
  local: {
    token: {
      property: 'token',
      required: true,
      type: 'Bearer',
      maxAge: 31536000,
    },
    user: {
      property: 'user',
      // autoFetch: false
    },
    endpoints: {
      login: { url: '/login', method: 'post' },
      logout: { url: '/logout', method: 'post' },
      user: { url: '/user', method: 'get' }
    }
  }
}
```

},